# Export PowerBI embedded report Forbidden

Tags: asp.net-core, powerbi, powerbi-embedded

I have my `ASP.NET Core` project with an embedded `PowerBI` report. The report is always shown correct. In the [Microsoft documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/developer/embedded/export-to), I read that now it is possible to export the report in different format. So, using the example, I put together the application. You have the code in [GitHub](https://github.com/erossini/PowerBIEmbedExport).

The problem I'm facing is when I call

```
// The 'Client' object is an instance of the Power BI .NET SDK
var export = await Client.Reports.ExportToFileInGroupAsync(
                          groupId, reportId, exportRequest);
```

This call raises an *Operation returned an invalid status code 'Forbidden'*.

[image: Operation returned an invalid status code 'Forbidden']

In the `Active Directory` I have all the required permissions and in particular

- Report.ReadWrite.All or Report.Read.All
- Dataset.ReadWrite.All or Dataset.Read.All

Also, I tried to use "Try it" in the documentation. In this case, I have another kind of error

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": "InvalidRequest",
    "message": "Report requested for export is not on dedicated capacity"
  }
}
```

[image]

How can I fix this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This API call requires so called "[dedicated capacity](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/developer/embedded/embedded-capacity)" to be assigned to the workspace, where the report is published. This means that you need to buy [Power BI Premium](https://powerbi.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi-premium/) (P or EM SKUs) or [Power BI Embedded](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/power-bi-embedded/) (A SKUs). You can read more about these in [Capacity and SKUs in Power BI embedded analytics](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/developer/embedded/embedded-capacity) article. The bottom line is that this is quote expensive (starts from ~$5000/month for P and from ~$625/month for A). You can buy A SKUs (A1, A2, A3, etc.) without any commitment, and pause it when it is not needed, while P and EM SKUs comes with (usually) annual commitment and you can't pause them. There is one more, recently new, option - to use [Premium Per User](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/admin/service-premium-per-user-faq) licensing (~$20/month/user). Depending on the SKU, you can run [different number of concurrent exports](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/developer/embedded/export-to#concurrent-requests) - from 1 (for the cheapest A1) to 24 (for the most expensive A6/P3 tier). The rest of the requests are queued.